# knockoutjs binding to a ko.observableArray of the selected child view model in a main view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

in knockoutjs i have a main view model which has a collection of child view models as in the following

```
//apply binding on document ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new MainviewModel);
});

//main view model, contains a child view models ko.observableArray
var MainviewModel = function()
{
    // ko.observableArray of subviewmodels
    this.subViewModels= ko.observableArray
    ([
        new SubViewModel('A'),
        new SubViewModel('B'),
        new SubViewModel('C')
    ]);

    //selected subviewmodel
    this.selectedSubViewModel = ko.observable();

    //set slected subviewmodel
    this.selectSubViewModel = function(subviewmodel)
    {
        this.selectedSubViewModel = selectedSubViewModel(subviewmodel);
    }
};

    //child view model, contains ko.observableArray of models
var SubViewModel = function(key)    
{ 
    this.key = key;   
    //load items from json based on key value...
    //ko.observableArray of subviewmodels
    this.items=ko.observableArray([new Model("car","4 wheels"), new Model("plane","can fly")]);
    //selected model
    this.selectedModel = ko.observable();
    //set selected model
    this.selectModel = function(item)
    {
        this.selectedModel = selectedModel(item);
    }
};

//model
var Model = function(word,defention)
{
    //properties
    this.word = word;
    this.defention = defention;
};
```

and in my html i have 2 lists changing selection in the first list should change the source of the second list, however when i change selection in list one nothing happens and when i debug in chrome i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedSubViewModel is not defined`

```
<!--main view model list view-->
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: subViewModels">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.selectedSubViewModel() == $data}, click: $parent.selectSubViewModel.bind($parent)">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: key"></h4>              
</a>
</div>

<!--selected sub view model list view-->
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: selectedSubViewModel.items">  
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="css: {active: $parent.selectedModel() == $data}, click: $parent.selectModel.bind($parent)">
     <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: word"></h4>
     <p class="list-group-item-text" data-bind="text: defention"></p>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `selectSubViewModel` and `selectModel` are incorectly trying to the set your `selectedSubViewModel` and `selectedModel` observables.

The correct syntax is:

```
this.selectSubViewModel = function(subviewmodel)
{
    this.selectedSubViewModel(subviewmodel);
}

this.selectModel = function(item)
{
    this.selectedModel(item);
}
```

See also in the documentation: [Reading and writing observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading_and_writing_observables)

However it won't make your code to work because when the `foreach: selectedSubViewModel.items` binding is executed for the first time `selectedSubViewModel` will be `null` and KO won't find the `selectedSubViewModel.items`.

To avoid this you can use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) to wrap your foreach. In this case your second list is only rendered if there is something in the `selectedSubViewModel` and you don't have to write `selectedSubViewModel.someproperty` it is enough to write `foreach: items` etc:

```
<!--selected sub view model list view-->
<!-- ko with: selectedSubViewModel -->
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">  
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" 
           data-bind="css: { active: $parent.selectedModel() == $data}, 
                      click: $parent.selectModel.bind($parent)">
     <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: word"></h4>
     <p class="list-group-item-text" data-bind="text: defention"></p>
     </a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feL5v/).